# How can I run a OWA_OPT_LOCK.CHECKSUM in all rows of a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, checksum

I would like to make loop to run the OWA_OPT_LOCK.CHECKSUM function in all rows of a table but I don't really know how to do it. Can someone help me?

I've done some advances on my code. Here is what I have now.
I'm trying to do something like the following code but it seems that the checksum function doesn't detect cursor's, just strings. Any tips?

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
CURSOR line_pointer IS    SELECT * FROM table_name;
resultado   line_pointer%ROWTYPE;
hash_value integer;
aux integer;
BEGIN
aux := 0;
hash_value:=0;
OPEN line_pointer;
LOOP
FETCH line_pointer INTO resultado;
aux := OWA_OPT_LOCK.CHECKSUM('resultado'); 
hash_value := hash_value + aux;
dbms_output.put_line(hash_value);
EXIT WHEN line_pointer%notfound;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Do you need to use OWA_OPT_LOCK.CHECKSUM or are you open to other utilities to hash a table?  The package [DBMS_SQLHASH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/appendixb.htm#CHDGHCAE) can be useful here, although it does have some issues (for example, you must sort the query you pass into it to get repeatable results).

Comment: I have tried the dbms_sqlhas package but it gave me a error like: 'DBMS_SQLHASH' must be declared'.I think that this error is related with my user privileges which I can't modify. I even tried to use the "authid current_user" feature to run dbms_sqlhash package but had no sucess (btw if you can give me a example of how to use the "authid current_user" to run the dbms_sqlhash package I would appreciate).

Comment: The package is not granted to anyone by default.  You'll need to have a DBA login as SYS and run `grant execute on dbms_sqlhash to YOUR_USER_NAME;`.  It should be a trivial change for a DBA to make.

Comment: I dont have that option. Guess I will have to work with OWA_OPT_LOCK.CHECKSUM.